# Selenium Java Chrome browser does not load the site URL page

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, timeout, selenium-chromedriver

In my Selenium Java project, Selenium does not load site URL page of my test site. In the console log it displays continuously

```
[1589602766.676][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602766.777][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602766.879][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602766.980][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.083][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.185][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.297][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.399][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.500][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.601][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.702][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.834][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602767.936][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.038][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.219][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.321][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.424][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.569][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.670][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.772][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.897][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602768.999][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.100][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.202][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.304][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.405][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.506][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.608][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.709][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.812][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602769.914][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602770.015][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602770.116][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602770.217][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602770.319][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1589602770.420][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100 ........
```

However when I manually load the site URL on my Chrome browser it is going to load and able to enter my login credentials in the initial page. I need VPN connection to load this site and I used the VPN connection as well when I load the page via Automation.

Any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: The log that you have got is normal for me. Could you please check whether the chromedriver version is same as the version of your chrome browser

Comment: Yes, I checked several other sites are loading properly for the same code. Only issue is with loading this site where continuously displaying the above code without loading the initial login page of the site.